# How to install robotframework RIDE on windows?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to install robotframework RIDE from few days and I tried following all the posts which I found googling, but still facing few problems.Below are the things which i followed and came upto :

1. I have successfully installed python2.7 --- as i get the version when I execute python --version
2. I have also installed robot-framework using pip install robot-framework
3. And also , wxpython
4. I tried downloading robot-framework ride from the this [website](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/robot-framework-ride/robotframework-ride-1.4.tar.gz), but when I uncompressed it, I was not able to find any executable file.  I also tried using pip to install ride, that is pip install robotframework ride, and got the below error:

   ```
   C:\Python27>pip install robotframework ride
   You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): robotframework in c:\p
   ython27\lib\site-packages
   Collecting ride
       Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6A30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
      Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6B30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
      Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6BD0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6CB0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6D90>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6B10>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6D10>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6E70>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030C6AB0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
     Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
   tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
   ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03186030>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
   org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ride/
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ride (from versions: )

       No matching distribution found for ride

   C:\Python27>
   ```

P.S I have made sure that PATH for python is added properly in environment variables.

Comment: You don't need RIDE in order to use robot framework. You might want to consider one of the other [available options](http://robotframework.org/#tools) (click on "EDITORS" to see a list of more than a dozen ways to edit robot framework files).

Answer (score 3):

Once you have installed python.
Please check the compatible version of wxPython with the version of python you are using.
I am using python 3.7 . 
Following are the steps needed to install ride:

1. **pip install -U wxPython**

[image]

2. **pip install robotframework-ride**

[image]

3. In the command prompt write **ride.py**

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong package name. There is no space between robotframework and ride - it is a hyphen.

```
pip install robotframework-ride
```

However, I do not see why you are getting a timeout error. Try again and see.

Comment: I had tried both the commands and it was not working !! But now it seems to be working !!! Anyways Thanks a lot for your answer  :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem was because i was connected to a Work network   :(   But it's working fine now...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you should install wxpython before RIDE.

You can download an appropriate installer from wxPython download page. For more information about the installation see http://wxpython.org pages in general.

Mine is wxpython-2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help: `pip install robotframework-ride --trusted-host pypi.org`

Answer (score 0):

I tried  with the latest versions of Python and wxPython, but they failed to install. In addition, at the robotframework-ride git page, there isn't an installer, eventhough they say there is one.

Be sure that for Python 2.7 you install a compatible vesion of wxPython. At the sourceforge website, look for the installer that ends with "py27". Only then you would be able to install RIDE correctly.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Pre-check
Check if python is already installed
python --version
pip --version
Check if robot framework is already installed
robot --version

Step 2: Install Python 2.7.14(32 bit)
check on cmd : python --version
pip --version

Step 3: Set Python in environment variables
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;
Check:
python --version
pip --version

Step 4 : Install robot framework
pip install robotframework
to uninstall : pip uninstall robotframework

Step 5 : Check on cmd :
robot --version
pybot --version

Step 6 : Download and install wxPython(32 bit)
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpy...
check with  : pip freeze
wxpython should be available

Step 7 : Install RIDE
pip install robotframework-ride
https://github.com/robotframework/RID...

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved either by disabling [Proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip) if you are using it or disconnecting VPN.