# pip install using proxy in a virtual environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, proxy-server

I work on a Ubuntu VM in my company's laptop which uses proxy server for connecting to internet.
After some research I found out how to install modules using `pip install` with proxy. For example, using this command I can install my virtualenv module:

```
sudo pip install --proxy=http://user:pass@<proxy_address>:<portnumber> virtualenv
```

However, after creating a virtual environment folder, activate it and then install a module using this pip command:

```
pip install --proxy=http://user:pass@<proxy_address>:<portnumber> pyperclip
```

I get this error:

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pyperclip/
```

If I use `sudo`, pip can download and install the module, but in system global package instead of in my virtual environment. It seems for me a permission issues in my Ubuntu and its proxy setting.

How can I tackle this issue, so that I can install a module locally in my virtualenv?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meanwhile, I know the solution. `pip` needs the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in capital letters, instead of `http_proxy`.
So append below text pattern at the end of your your '~/.bashrc'

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:pass@proxyaddress:port
export HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:pass@proxyaddress:port
export HTTPS_PROXY
```

Then, run `source ~/.bashrc`
Now you can install all python packages using `pip` in your Ubuntu VM with proxy login.

Comment: Does not work inside my corporate proxy. I get the below error -



     Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/rasa-core/

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use?
Another solution for Ubuntu 16.04 is to append the proxy entries in the file "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf".
`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:pass@proxyadress:portnumber";`
`Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:pass@proxyadress:portnumber";`

Comment: Thanks. I am now using CNTLM to bypass my company proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Do not activate the virtualenv and run your `pip install --proxy ...` command with the full path to your virtualenv pip i.e.

`C:\Users\name\myvenv\Scripts\pip install --proxy=http://user:pass@<proxy_address>:<portnumber> virtualenv`

Comment: this did the trick for me when VS Code was trying to search for extensions after setting up virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to exit out of virtualenv and install packages offline. Download packages with:

```
pip download -d <path/to/downloads/> {package_name | -r requirements.txt}
```

Then enter your virtualenv, install packages with:

```
pip install {package_name| -r requiements.txt} --no-index --find-links <path/to/downloads/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not activate the virtualenv and run your pip instl --proxy ... command with the full path to your virtualenv pip i.e.

C:\Users\name\myvenv\Scripts\pip install --proxy=http://user:pass@<proxy_address>: virtualenv