# PIp exception error while insalling django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, proxy

I am installing django in ubuntu using the command `pip install django==1.11.2` but i am getting the following error

```
    Collecting django==1.11.2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 555, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 753, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 230, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 832, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  .
```

.

.
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
        total -= 1
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
i have also tried `sudo -H pip install django==1.11.2` still the same error

Comment: `OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required` Does that give you a hint?

Comment: i have tried `export http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy:port"` but no help while `sudo apt update` is working fine

Comment: HTTPS_PROXY in capital letters

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398396/oserror-tunnel-connection-failed-407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: i already did that but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with your internet connection. I believe you are under proxy. You need to set the proxy.

Comment: Check the error message OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398396/oserror-tunnel-connection-failed-407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16,04

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877871/pip-install-using-proxy-in-a-virtual-environment/39208484