# pip connection timeout robotframework-requests library

Tags: python, pip

[image]I was working on robot framework (RIDE) for testing, and pip was working fine and I was able to install the robotframework libraries using pip. But now whenever I try to install any python library, it shows me an error like the following.

for example 
`pip install robotframework-requests` gives me the error:

`Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x030F2E90>, 'Connection to 10.7.0.140 t
imed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-requests/`

I get similar error for any library I try to install. From searching around the error, I found it might be due to some proxy settings. Can anyone help me with fixing pip. It would be a great help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)

Comment: I have seen that answer, but it didn't work for me! @Robert Valencia

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
python -m pip install --isolated --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --isolated --upgrade urllib3
python -m pip install --isolated robotframework-requests
```

Comment: `  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03180BB0>, 'Connection to 10.7.0.140 t
imed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/robotframework-requests/`

Comment: After which command line does the error occur? Does it occur during the upgrades or just during robotframework-requests installation?

Comment: Hmm. Why is it trying to connect to 10.7.0.140? Can you change it to pypi.python.org and try again?

Comment: I reinstalled my setup, and the problem didn't occur again! So maybe that's the solution

Answer (score 0):

please do this to change your LAN setting,

- Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
- Click Network and Internet, and then click Internet Options.
- In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Connections tab.

  - Click the LAN Settings button.
  - and uncheck server proxy