# How to configure PIP per config file to use a proxy (with authentification)?

Tags: python, proxy, pip, ini

I used to set up environment evariables http_proxy and https_proxy (with user + password) in the past to use Pip (on Windows) behind a corporate proxy. But recently I needed to tell Pip to use a proxy without setting up environment variables as this conflicted with git configuration in combination with SSL Certificates which I get to work only by removing environment variables for proxy.

Fortunately you can configure PIP with an pip.ini file as described here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

The detailed answer to my own question follows below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here are the steps how to configure proxy (with auth.) in pip's config file (pip.ini)

1. (if it does not already exist) Create a folder named 'pip' and inside it a file named 'pip.ini' as described here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file (location an name may differ per platform - e.g. on Windows it's %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini)
2. edit pip.ini file and add

   ```
   [global]
   proxy = http://user:password@proxy_name:port
   ```
3. That's it!

Example for proxy with authentification (user + password):

proxy = http://butch:secret@proxyname:1234

proxyname can be an IP adress, too

Example for proxy without auth.:

proxy = http://proxyname:1234

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem... I didn't need username or password, just the proxy IP.

Comment: In cmd, do I just need to write "pip install requests" for example? Will the ini be automatically checked? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: In Windows 10, the path will be:  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini

Comment: this works to me but naming the conf file `pip.conf` instead of `pip.ini` as the docs say (using ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: exactly, what does the `pip install...`  command look like now after setting up this configuration file?

Comment: @TMOTTM `pip install ...` will not change. e.g. `pip install robotframework`. If u do not setup a pip.conf (or pip.ini) you will have to provide proxy info as cli option whenever you call pip (see the other answers below), e.g. `pip install robotframework --proxy https://user_name:password@proxyname:port`

Answer (score 26):

A little easier with:

```
pip config set global.proxy http://{host}:{port}
```

and it will persist the setting automagically

```
Writing to C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
```

Comment: I have used this after activating my virtualenv with pyenv. A configuration has been created just for this environment and it solved my issue with corp proxy. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

In order to add a proxy option in the terminal the following line solved the problem for me:

```
pip install package_name_here --proxy https://user_name:password@proxyname:port
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set proxy option while installing the package.
example:

```
pip install --proxy userid:password@proxy.domain.com:yourport
```

Answer (score 2):

If package that you are trying to install has dependencies it's best to create pip.ini for system wide configuration, in windows you can do this in powershell:

```
mkdir c:\programdata\pip\
new-item c:\programdata\pip\pip.ini
```

and add this to your pip.ini

```
[global]
proxy = http://domain\user:pwd@proxy_hostname_or_ip:port
```

and then everything should work fine, as HTTP_PROXY variable didn't work for me.

**Make sure** to save file as ansi or windows1252 in VSCode as UTF files are not read properly.

Comment: Pip uses variables with prefix `PIP_`. The rest is the option name in uppercase with underscores. On Unix: `export PIP_PROXY=...` on Windows: `set PIP_PROXY=...` --- See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables