# pip install package via proxy

Tags: python, pip

I tried to pip install using proxy, the proxy setting is correct because it works for npm install . what i tried is as below shown but got error message. any idea will be more than welcome!

```
set http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server>:<port>

set https_proxy=https://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server>:<port>

pip install Flask

Collecting Flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
```

Comment: You aren't per chance using sudo with the pip install? Have you tried passing the proxy directly with --proxy?

Answer (score 12):

```
pip install packageName --proxy proxy_Server:portnumber

ex: pip install numpy --proxy https://myproxy@myserver.com:9090
```

Comment: You may add some documentation instead of pasting code without any details.

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611028/2653663 it looks like it should be

```
set https_proxy=<domain><username>:<password>@<proxy_server>:<port>
```

So port instead of ip.

Comment: sorry typeerror i do used  <username>:<password>@<proxy_server>:<port>

Comment: what should i type for <domain>

Answer (score 1):

`set http_proxy=...` and `set https_proxy=...`. should be enough if the proxy works.

Please run the following command to make sure that it works:

```
curl https://google.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from: [@Anwar_Husain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1921855/anwar-husain)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69568878/2282427

```bash
pip config set global.proxy http://{host}:{port}
```

Advantage: lets pip handle his config file.