# Trying to install selenium package in Pycharm (Python and Selenium) and getting timeout error message

Tags: python, selenium

ran the command:: pip install -U Selenium and getting timeout error message.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'Connect
TimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03F4
9670>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/selenium/
```

Comment: this may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip

Comment: Are you on a network that restricts outgoing connections?

Comment: possible. I don't have proxy server address, Actually using Automatic configuration script. have no idea how to tweak this::  pip install --proxy=http://proxy.example.com numpy

Comment: Eg: http://proxy2.....:8080/proxy.pac  how do I modify this proxy script

Comment: @John Gordon: Yes, you are right. the network restricts connections, so that I changed to another network and I'm able to install packages. Thanks John..