# pip install is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to install pygame with pip install . but every time i tried i faced to this error.

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))
>   after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))': /simple/pygame-1-9-3-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after
>   connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))': /simple/pygame-1-9-3-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after
>   connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))': /simple/pygame-1-9-3-cp36-cp36m-win-amd64/ Operation
>   cancelled by user*

I have done it with other libraries but I faced the same problem

Comment: your firewall is blocking? I advise that you download a pre-built wheel in that case using your browser then install with the local wheel

Comment: where can I download wheel and how to install it

Comment: You can download a wheel [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). If you use Python 3.6 64 bit you need this wheel: `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`. Then navigate to the directory that contains the wheel and install it with pip by entering `py -3.6 -m pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: which wheel should I download

Comment: wheel‑0.26.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl
wheel‑0.30.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl

Comment: I have installed correctly wheel and it successfully installed. but when I try it with pygame it occur an error

Comment: and this is the error

Comment: Requirement 'pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Try the 32 bit pygame wheel: `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`

Comment: aha .. The 32-bit version of pygame worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in windows. My antivirus was blocking PIP requests. Try disabling your antivirus(in my case manually killed it from task manager).

Answer (score 2):

Go to this [Website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), download the pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl file, open cmd, change directory to the folder you have the .whl file end type:

`pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` .

This works when you are trying to install packages and firewalls are blocking the connection.

Comment: Requirement 'pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: I have a windows 10 64 bit and my python version is 3.6.3

Comment: Do you have (or had) any other python version installed on tour machine? Maybe the pip in the path is not python 3.6s. You May try using the full path of pip, something like: `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: You have the correct file. Your errror means that the cmd is not in the same folder as the .whl. Try this: Go to the folder where the .whl is, and with the SHIFT key pressed right click on the folder, choose "open command window here" and then: `pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

I had same error message when I tried to install Python packages on my laptop with Windows 10 OS.
I tried all methods recommended online and it still didn't work. I have been noticing for a while that Windows 10 automatically set proxy off causing Internet access problem sometime.

Then I googled with keywords: 'windows 10 automatic proxy setting off'. Someone mentioned to modify regedit key value of [ProxyEnabled=1] under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

I opened the regedit and found it's [ProxyEnabled=1]. I compared HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
with another workstation with relatively clean image. It's [ProxyEnabled=0] and no other extra entry for Proxy.

Solution: set ProxyEnabled=0 and delete any other Proxy entries.
It worked successfully!  pip install package_name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pip` is not connecting to the internet. I have a few options --
I don't know if they will work, but you can try them.

1. Try to reinstall `pip` (`pip3` if using python3) I had to do this on my
    systeme, as `pip3` didn't work initally either.
2. Check and see if you can ping a website from your terminal to check           connectivity. You could have an error with your terminal (if using linux) and not with python itself.

Good luck, and hope this helps!

Comment: I think I have pip3 and there is not any problem with my connection I have tried ping

Comment: Specifically, you should type `pip install -h`, and look under `--index-url` to see what your default python package index url is.  (It's usually `pypi.org/simple`.)  Then ping this url (e.g. `ping pypi.org`)