# Issue with installing xmltodict on python 3.6.3 on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to install xmltodict module on my existing python 3.6.3 on Windows 7 machine. I tried the below steps but getting error. Please help me.

Python version:

```
C:\Users\MaS>pythona
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
 on win32
```

Tried the below steps:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MaS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip.exe install xmltodict
Collecting xmltodict
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError '<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACF70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACE70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACDB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACBB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmltodict (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xmltodict

C:\Users\MaS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip3.6.exe
install xmltodict
Collecting xmltodict
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACCF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACDF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACFD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACF50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACE90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmltodict (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xmltodict

C:\Users\MaS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip3.exe in
stall xmltodict
Collecting xmltodict
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACED0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACF70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACF30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACE70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x033ACD70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/xmltodict/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmltodict (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xmltodict

C:\Users\MaS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459747/pip-install-is-not-working)

Comment: Dear Idlehands,
I am not able to follow the post you mentioned as it talks about gntp module. Could you please provide me steps to install my target xmltodict  module manually (if possible). Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the xmltodict module, but a quick google search brought me to here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict#downloads .  Try download the whl file and follow the instruction on the thread linked.  Based on the thread it seems it's a firewall issue.  Did you have trouble installing other modules?

Comment: Thanks a lot Idlehands for your time. By combining your two comments, my problem is solved. Have provided the details in Answer. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped.  Thanks for posting your final solution in detail.

Answer (score 2):

First of all 'Many Thanks' to Idlehands (who commented on my post). Combining his two comments the problem is solved.
Steps I took:
Step-1: Downloaded the file 'xmltodict-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (md5)' from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict#downloads as mentioned by Idlehands.
Step-2: Launched a command prompt in Admin privileged (I am not sure if it works without Admin or not)
Step-3: Go to the location where the file (in step-1) is located.
Step-4: Run the pip install command.
Please see below:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\MaS\Downloads

C:\Users\MaS\Downloads>pip install xmltodict-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\MaS\downloads\xmltodict-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: xmltodict
Successfully installed xmltodict-0.11.0

C:\Users\MaS\Downloads>