# How can you fix this error while installing PIP on Windows 10?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install pip on my Windows machine. I get the latest version of get-pip.py from `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/`

Then, I fire up the command prompt, locate `get-pip.py` on my system and try the command:

`python get-pip.py`

Everytime I try this, I get the following error:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Most Python installers will include pip by default these days.

Comment: My first guess is a proxy is interrupting/blocking pip from connecting.

Comment: Are you using the latest python version? python --version

Comment: @DanielPryden I am using Python version 3.6.6.

Comment: @mikeg, I think you maybe right

Comment: At work we use a really evil proxy, I fight it everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to set the proxy for Windows. In the command prompt do the following.

```
set HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy_address:proxy_port"
set HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy_address:proxy_port"
```

Notice that both the HTTP and the HTTPS proxy use the EXACT same string.

Comment: What do I fill in as proxy_address??

Comment: You will have to know the address and port of the proxy you are behind. This solution is only if you are behind a proxy. Is this happening at work or at home or on public wifi?

Comment: This is at work. How do I know what the address and port of the proxy is? Any way to check?

Comment: what specific os version?  look at this post -- https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using

Comment: I found out my proxy address and set the HTTP/HTTPS proxies. Still nothing :( getting the same error when trying to install pip.

Comment: That's good to hear. To start, what version of python are you running?

Comment: I am running Python 3.6.6

Comment: i checked, apparently it is not installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186199/discussion-between-mikeg-and-krithika-raghavendran).

Answer (score 1):

two initial things:

1) what version of python have you installed? 
    new versions come with pip installed by default.
2) have you tried running cmd as administrator ?
    ive had issues with stuff in the past that running cmd as 
    admin has resolved.

let us know!

Comment: I have Python version 3.6.6. No, I haven't tried running cmd as administrator (I work in an office where I need special permission for administrator access)

Comment: Okay, if you are trying from office probably the IS might disabled access to those IP addresses -- proxies, etc. That's why its not able to download.

Comment: You can try downloading the file manually and install https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

1. Download the get-pip.py installer script. 
2. Open the Command Prompt and navigate to the get-pip.py file
3. Run the following command: python get-pip.py

Comment: yeah, itl most likely be a restriction set up by your office sys admins

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the file manually and install https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

1. Download the get-pip.py installer script.
2. Open the Command Prompt and navigate to the get-pip.py file
3. Run the following command: python get-pip.py

Comment: then these answers might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459747/pip-install-is-not-working