# Cant install pip PyMySQL using Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pymysql

I tried to download the pip install PyMySQL on my Anaconda prompt (Im using Spyder as IDE). Its not working. I received this error. Someone who knows how to fix it? Iam using Python version 3.7.4 64-bit. Thank you in advance :)

```
(base) C:\Users\AK>pip install PyMySQL
Collecting PyMySQL
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E5EC2F84C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/pymysql/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E5EC30CC48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/pymysql/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E5EC319408>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/pymysql/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E5EC319908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/pymysql/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E5EC319B88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/pymysql/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyMySQL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyMySQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to an antivirus or some other program on your computer interfering with network connections (see [pip install is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459747/pip-install-is-not-working)).

I am able to install PyMySQL with the following:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

There are a few possible solutions.

1. Install with conda: `conda install pymysql`
2. Download the wheel for PyMySQL and install it using that file.

   - Go to https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#files and download the `.whl` file.
   - Run `pip install path/to/PyMySQL-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
3. If antivirus is in fact playing a role, then I'm not sure what to do, but google is your friend.

Comment: they are using anaconda which is also very explicit about which version of python to use

Comment: @jakub If I use your command I get : 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AK28 - then use `pip install`. I do recommend using the `python -m pip` syntax though, because it is more explicit about which `pip` you are referring to. This can prevent installing into the wrong environment.

Comment: @jakub Finally! Solution 2 worked for me. Thank you very much!