# Pip Install - error message when installing packages Python 2.7 Anaconda / Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

until recently, I had no problems installing packages using

```
pip install package_name
```

through command prompt.  However, recently, I started receiving the following error message for 99% of packages I attempt to install (note: if the package is already installed, i do get "requirement already satisfied error").

```
          Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) 
    after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
        NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x00000000041D2A90>: Failed to establish a new connection:
 [Errno 10061]  No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it',))': /simple/pattern/
```

Any idea on whats going on here, and how I can go about fixing it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try upgrading pip `pip install --upgrade pip` or on windows `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `easy_install pip`

Comment: ok, this actually gave me the same error as above, 4 times, then said the requirement already satisfied.  Any idea on whats happening ?
error:

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000004281780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/pip/

Comment: Googling the error, it looks like a network issue on your side. I can run `pip install pattern` from here with no problem. Has your network changed? Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: If you have got a proxy: `sudo -H pip install pattern --proxy="my_proxy_name:port"`

Comment: yeah, no dice.  same errors.  One thing i should specify is that im using jupyter notebook.  However, same error message. 
In the past few days i have been working with a script that switches out proxies every run (via requests library), so maybe that had something to do with this error

Comment: It sounds network related which is the issue you're having. Tricky to help you further but hopefully you can focus on the proxy issue.

Comment: yup.  sounds like a network issue of some sort. 
Just tried pip uninstall pandas... and now can't install it :-/  oops.
will try to diagnose and post on here once i figure it out.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: mystery solved!  Was a simple setting in windows that i had to change.  Answer is as follows: pip doesn't work if you are using a proxy server for installing packages. To fix it: Go to control panel -> Internet options -> Connections ->LAN Settings ->Unmark 'use proxy server' options. Try using pip after this, it should work. You can start using proxy server after installing the package.  .  

Note - the original answer is here, by The_Vats
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery Solved - this was a proxy setting within windows.  Answer, provides by The_Vatts in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip) is as follows:

**Go to control panel -> Internet options -> Connections ->LAN Settings ->Unmark 'use proxy server' options.**

Judging by the other thread, this may not be exactly what some people are looking for, but this accomplished what i needed.

Comment: What about linux like systems?