# Error to install packages in python

Tags: python-3.x, installation, package

I can try to install packages in python 3.6.4 with pip but I found many errors. I try  also command like:  `easy_install, pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>, pip install --ignore-installed <package>`. The error result always the same:

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E91DCF04E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/<package>/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E91DCF0BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/<package>/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E91DCF0748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/<package>/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E91DCF0C18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/<package>/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E91DCF02E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/<package>/
```

I think that I don't reach the https://pypi.python.org/simple

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by any chance?

Comment: All right I'm behind a proxy, I use pip install --proxy=https://user@mydomain:port somepackage to install the package. Thanks for the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I *think* that I don't reach the https://pypi.python.org/simple/

If nothing else works, still try to open https://pypi.python.org/simple/ manually in a browser. There are download links there for every version of every major Python package. In my case, the install didn't work in Windows 10 from my Visual Studio, so I downloaded every package manually and then installed them one-by-one manually again, something like

C:\Users\myself>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\scripts\pip" install C:\Users\myself\Downloads\jupyter-1.0.0.tar.gz

If the install says another module can't be found then download and install the missing one and repeat the command for the original one, see may be something else is missing and so forth. Takes a while but gets you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the packages manually on https://pypi.org/, downloading the respective .whl files and installing them via the (Anaconda) command line was the only thing that worked for me on a Windows 10 machine.