# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysftp'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am getting following error while trying to use 'pysftp' module in Jupyter Notebook:

End Goal: Download files from Unix server onto Windows folder automatically through a web-based application written in Python.

In this process, when I try to connect to WINSCP in order to allow python code to login to Unix server(username@hostname), I used 'pystftp' module however I get below error message:

Error Message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysftp'`

**Action taken:**

1. `pip list` - to view the already installed packages in python; I doesn't show pysftp
2. `pip install pysftp` - to install pysftp module; get below error when ran this in jupyter notebook

error message:

```
Collecting pysftp
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227A34A2400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pysftp/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227A33BC4A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pysftp/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227A33BCE80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pysftp/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227A33BCEB8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pysftp/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227A33BCE48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pysftp/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysftp (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pysftp
```

Request:
Please direct and help me achieve my end goal.

I am writing a code in Jupyter Notebook

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: I think your internet connection isn't stable enough for `pip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error to install packages in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192842/error-to-install-packages-in-python)

Comment: pip was never able to complete the installation of your module, possibly due to poor connectivity. (You should see a *successfully installed* message) Once the module is installed and available for Python to use, you will not see the error.

Answer (score 2):

At first suggestion: You should check the **location for PYTHON installation path** and from that directory **go to cmd** -> and type: **pip installs pysftp**. If the installation is successful then the problem is in your interpreter selection where your scripts are running.