# Handshake operation timed out error while installing modules

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.8

I installed python 3.8 on my laptop. It was all fine then I was setting up modules so I can start my work I installed one module `pyttsx3` then it asked to upgrade pip I did that then I had to install kivy but when I did it gave me some error.

The whole error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 

connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1108: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/kivy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1108: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/kivy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1108: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/kivy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1108: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/kivy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1108: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/kivy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy
```

My internet is good working fine
Help Me!!

What I tried:
I tried disabling proxy but it turns on automatically when I do pip install something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Pip Install - Proxy Error - 'Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979354/python-pip-install-proxy-error-cannot-connect-to-proxy-oserror)

Comment: problem is not with the module or internet connection, the problem is with how are you handling the proxy. Above question would help you resolving the error

Comment: No this question doesn't help me because I don't even use proxy servers or something like that

Comment: I also have proxy OFF but whenever I try to pip install something it shows the error.

Please Help

Comment: python on your system is `32bit` or `64bit` and which operating system you are using? also try this to install `Kivy` once `pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`

Comment: 64 bit is python. OS is Win7 basic.

Nope this is the same error

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566070/1321247) could solve the problem. But it is not up-voted, so I cannot flag a duplication question. I tried to post the answer here, and it is removed due to duplication. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

When opening cmd:
-Run as Administrator

Then you can: `pip install xxx`