# Cannot pip install anything, get 'Cannot connect to proxy' error

Tags: python, pip, proxy, http-proxy

Other solutions suggested turning off proxies and altering the system32 'hosts' file. I can't do either as I am using a company computer and need the former to connect to the company network and I don't have admin privileges for the latter. The error:

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1112: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/selenium/

Anyone have this experience? Specifically working for solutions that would work on a company computer

Comment: I used to have issues pip installing modules. Then I discovered the issue was because of the pip version. Pip version 21 does not work in some environments/systems. I had to downgrade my Pycharm and Python so I can use pip version 20. Pip version 20 downwards work fine. Python 37 and 38 pip versions are okay for pip installation of modules. Pycharm 19.3 downwards are okay for pip installation of modules because they have pip version 20 downwards. I really don't know why pip version 21 is not working for me and others

Comment: I tried downgrading pip and that didn't work as well. Also I've just been using the command prompt to try and use pip install

Comment: Uninstall your Python and Pycharm if you're using pycharm, then install older versions of them. They come with older version of pip

Answer (score 0):

- Disclaimer: following is a shameless rip-off of [httpx trouble
  shooting guide](https://www.python-httpx.org/troubleshooting/), but people need help, like, here, so...

Resolution: it is likely that you've set up your proxies like this...

```
proxies = {
  "http": "http://myproxy.org",
  "https": "https://myproxy.org",
}
```

Using this setup, you're trying to connect to the proxy using HTTP for HTTP requests, and using HTTPS for HTTPS requests.

But if you get the error above, it is likely that your proxy doesn't support connecting via HTTPS. Don't worry: that's a common gotcha.

Change the scheme of your HTTPS proxy to http://... instead of https://...:

```
proxies = {
  "http": "http://myproxy.org",
  "https": "http://myproxy.org",
}
```

This can be simplified to:

```
proxies = "http://myproxy.org"
```

For more information, see [Proxies: FORWARD vs TUNNEL](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#forward-vs-tunnel).