# getting error while installing python modules using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

[image: Image link for error msg]

Hi i am trying to install several modules using a text file which contains module name and there version that needs to be installed.

I am using the command pip install -r requirement.txt, but i am getting the following error.
Please refer the image for the error.

```
Error Message:

Retrying(Retry(total=4, connect=None,read=None,redirect=None,status=None)) after connection
broken by 'ProxyError(Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2,No such file or directory))':simple/anisole

The user is not able to install requirement.txt
```

Comment: Show the error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have added the Error Message as well.

Comment: @user9714773 can you add packages you are trying to install. There are few more probabilities apart from those listed by Arun Kumar.

Comment: Which system are you using? If windows try to install packages again by elevated prompt (Run Command prompt as admin and install packages) otherwise, if using ubuntu then with `sudo` in front of the command.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it can few one of the below issues:

1. I can see file not found issue. It could be that your requirements.txt is not at the location where you are running the script. Try providing the full path of the file or check the file path.
2. Proxy error: This error can come when using a VM to do your experiments. for this check out this link [Python - Pip Install - Proxy Error - 'Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979354/python-pip-install-proxy-error-cannot-connect-to-proxy-oserror)

if this still does not work. kindly share the complete details of the path and the project with your requirements.txt. (better to share the git repo).

Answer (score 0):

What usually works for me when this happens is to uninstall the entire module and installing it with

```
pip3 install module
```

If this does not work, I don't know :/