# Error in Python Package Shap installation

Tags: python, shap

I am trying to install Python package "Shap"
Below is the command I used to install shap:

> pip install shap --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org bs4

But it is giving error as below:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/shap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/shap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/shap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/shap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/shap/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shap (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shap
```

I tried to install legacy or old versions also.
My python version is 3.9.7, installed using anaconda. What do you suggest to do?
Shall I upgrade my python version and if yes then to which version? Will it be a problem for other existing libraries if I upgrade python? Please guide me in this installation.

Comment: How did you try to install it?

Comment: `Current Version of Shap is : 0.40.0` <- I don't get this part. Is it installed or not? What command did you use to try to install and can you put the complete output you get into your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I am trying using pip install shap.

Comment: @FlyingTeller : By current version, I mean shap package current version mentioned on site, not on my machine. I have not installed shap yet.

Comment: Where is `/simple/shap` coming from in the error message? Is that part of some command you typed?

Comment: No. `/simple/shap` is not part of my command, You can see my command above. I am installing through jupyter

Comment: `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy` this is very relevant. Your proxy settings are not correct for your network

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Pip Install - Proxy Error - 'Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979354/python-pip-install-proxy-error-cannot-connect-to-proxy-oserror)

Comment: After going through above Link, I added proxy as:                                               `import sys, os, os.path
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = "http://xxxproxy.xxx.com: 8080"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "https://xxxproxy.xxx.com: 8080"`.                               And it is giving below error now.                                                                         
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Failed to parse: https://xxxproxy.xxx.com: 8080`. Is it because In my VM's Proxy settings there was HTTP section and not HTTPS section.

Comment: Hello Intelligent people, pls help me in shap installation?

Comment: I am getting error for `https://` connection error. Pls Give me some direction on this