# Pip Connection broke

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Selenium module into my scripts folder for windows 10, however it seems that when I run `pip` it gives me a connection error

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002546B413DA0>,
'Connection to proxy.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': 
/simple/selenium/
```

I have downloaded Selenium from their website, however i am very new to this sort of thing and would like to know what i can do exactly to install this module locally.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip

Comment: @kohkiMametani I have tried that but it gives me the same error. Is there a way i can drag the files into the pip.exe or somesort?

Comment: Can you install modules other than selenium?

Comment: I somehow managed to install openpyxl by dragging its contents into easypip.exe i believe.

Comment: Normally you can install selenium by typing `pip install selenium` in console and after that, you need to download a webdriver you like. I guess there's something wrong in your python/pip env, most likely because of the proxy setting. It's really hard to install modules without pip.

Comment: is there any solution to this?

Comment: The only solution I can come up with is passing the proxy settings like the link I posted at first. My guess is you did it in a wrong way. Or, a worse situation is any other security like a firewall blocking the internet connection, which I've never experienced.