# downloading, installing the packages and modules

Tags: python

I am facing the below error message when i try to install any of the package or model

```
C:\Users\A492542\Downloads>pip install requests==2.21.0
Collecting requests==2.21.0
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06B24850>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
```

Please help me out. Also could any of them let me know where i can download the packages and modules?

Comment: Have you check, if you can access the https://pypi.org/project/requests/ hompage. If not it can be a problem with your network. If this works fine maybe try without the version. Because 2.21.0 is the latest release (`pip install requests` or `pip3 install requests` for python3).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)